# Delphi : Avoid editing a column in TDBgrid

Tags: delphi, editing, tdbgrid, in-place-editor

I know that using a column's readonly property, i can avoid editing its field value. But this doesn't stop the inplace editor to show itself.
I need a way to make the column not only protected but "untouchable".
Is there a way, please ?

Comment: Although [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16043353/512728) is for cells, it may help you get started

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you want correctly, you can do this quite simply, by creating a custom TDBGrid descendant and overriding
its `CanEditShow` method, as this determines whether the grid's `InplaceEditor` can be created:

```
type
  TMyDBGrid = class(TDBGrid)
  private
    FROColumn: Integer;
  protected
    function CanEditShow : Boolean; override;
  public
    property ROColumn : Integer read FROColumn write FROColumn;
  end;

function TMyDBGrid.CanEditShow: Boolean;
begin
  Result := Inherited CanEditShow;
  Result := Result and (Col <> ROColumn);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MyDBGrid := TMyDBGrid.Create(Self);
  MyDBGrid.ROColumn := 1;
  MyDBGrid.DataSource := DataSource1;
  MyDBGrid.Parent := Self;
[...]
```

This minimalist example just defines one grid column by number as being one
where the `InplaceEditor` is not permitted; obviously you could use any mechanism
you like to identify the column(s) for which `CanEditShow` returns False.

Note that the code above doesn't account for the fact that the column numbering of the grid changes if you turn off the `Indicator` column (i.e. set `Options.dgIndicator` to False);

Obviously, you get more flexibility for customizing which columns are permitted an InplaceEditor by using an assignable event as in

```
type

  TAllowGridEditEvent = procedure(Sender : TObject; var AllowEdit : Boolean) of object;

  TMyDBGrid = class(TDBGrid)
  private
    FOnAllowEdit: TAllowGridEditEvent;
  protected
    function CanEditShow : Boolean; override;
    procedure DoAllowEdit(var AllowEdit : Boolean);
  public
    property OnAllowEdit : TAllowGridEditEvent read FOnAllowEdit write FOnAllowEdit;
  end;

function TMyDBGrid.CanEditShow: Boolean;
begin
  Result := Inherited CanEditShow;
  if Result then
    DoAllowEdit(Result);
end;

procedure TMyDBGrid.DoAllowEdit(var AllowEdit: Boolean);
begin
  if Assigned(FOnAllowEdit) then
    FOnAllowEdit(Self, AllowEdit);
end;

procedure TForm1.AllowEdit(Sender: TObject; var AllowEdit: Boolean);
var
  Grid : TMyDBGrid;
begin
  Grid := Sender as TMyDBGrid;
  AllowEdit := Grid.Col <> 1;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MyDBGrid := TMyDBGrid.Create(Self);
  MyDBGrid.ROColumn := 1;
  MyDBGrid.DataSource := DataSource1;
  MyDBGrid.Parent := Self;
  MyDBGrid.OnAllowEdit := AllowEdit;
  [...]
```

If you don't like creating the grid in code, you could put it in a custom package and install it
in the IDE **or**, if your Delphi version is recent enough, implement the
`CanEditShow` in a `class helper`.

Comment: I add the flexibility i want by this way :
    `function TMyDBGrid.CanEditShow: Boolean;
    begin
      Result := Inherited CanEditShow;
      Result := not Columns[col].ReadOnly;
    end;`

I'm wondering why Embarcadero didn't