# DBGrid set some cell as readonly

Tags: delphi, dbgrid

With dbgrid, we can set some Column as read only

```
DBGrid1.Columns[C].ReadOnly := True;
```

In my case, i need to set some cell (and **NOT all cell in this Column** ) as read only.

[image: dbgrid]

You can see in my image, if i have "`No`" value in `field1` we should enable edit on field `Tx`. But if i have "`Yes`" value we should set `Tx` field as `ReadOnly`.

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16042975/set-some-cells-in-tdbgrid-to-editable

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it is possible.  The key to a solution to this is the fact that the dataset cursor of the dataset connected to the grid is synchronised to the current row in the grid, because of the way TDBGrid is coded.

So, all you need to do is to set up an `AfterScroll` event for the dataset and put your code to set the grid's ReadOnly property in that.  In my case, the following works fine:

```
procedure TForm1.CDS1AfterScroll(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
  DBGrid1.Columns[4].ReadOnly := Odd(CDS1.FieldByName('ID').AsInteger);
end;
```

Obviously, in your case you could test the contents of your Yes/No field.

If you want the grid to react immediately to a change in the value of the field that you are using to determine whether the column should be read-only, you should execute the same code in the dataset's `AfterEdit` event.

Comment: @user6751794: Did this answer your q?